# How to display text (with # of records) in each of 4 quadrants in Tableau?

Tags: parameters, tableau-api

I am creating a Tableau visual in which I have created 4 Quadrants using Reference Lines. I have also created 2 Parameters (using Sets) with which i can move the quadrants as desired.

I am trying to display a Dynamic text in all the 4 quadrants which displays the # of Records in each quadrant. As and when I change the parameters, the numbers in the text should also change according to the number of records in the respective quadrants.

Is there a way to do the same in Tableau ?

I am also attaching a screen shot of the visual i have created so far.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCMJM.png)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can add 4 floating sheets on the top of your dashboard (one on each quadrant).
2. In the filter pane for each of the 4 sheets, add the calculation field (created for calculating the quadrant of points).
3. Add "Number of Records" field to Label in each of the 4 sheets.
   Here is a dashboard link for your reference: https://public.tableau.com/profile/arunima4660#!/vizhome/SO_Ans_2/Dashboard1

(Also, it's showing up 4 records in Q1, since 2 of the data points are overlapping the other 2 per the data entered)

Comment: Thank you so very much Arunima. This is what I was looking for. That solved my problem.

Comment: You could also create area annotations as a similar approach. Be sure to upvote and accept Arunima’s answer

Comment: Thanks Alex! I will also give it a shot using area annotations.